# JQuery DOM get Binded attribudes

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a code

```
 $(".showerPr").on('click', '.prototypeDiv',function(){

 });
```

HTML looks like

```
<div class='showerPr' data-id='3'>
<div class='prototypeDiv' data-id='5'><div>
</div>
```

Is there some solution to get showerPr data-id and prototypeDiv data-id seperately?

somethink like

```
$(this).attr('data-id');
$(this).before().attr('data-id');
```

:-D thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`.showerPr` isn't `before()` the `.prototypeDiv` element, it's the parent element

```
var proto  = $(this).data('id');
var shower = $(this).parent().data('id');
```

```js
$(".showerPr").on('click', '.prototypeDiv',function(){
  var proto  = $(this).data('id');
  var shower = $(this).parent().data('id');
  
  $('#result').html('prototypeDiv : ' + proto + '<br />' + 'showerPr : ' + shower)
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='showerPr' data-id='3'>
    <div class='prototypeDiv' data-id='5'>Click Me !!!<div>
</div>

<br/><br/>
<div id="result"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

@adeneo is right, `.showerPr` is the parent element. You may want to check the [Traversing Methods for jQuery](https://api.jquery.com/category/traversing/).

Here are the snippets.

```js
$(".prototypeDiv").on('click', function(){
  alert($(this).data('id'));
  alert($(this).parent().data('id'));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='showerPr' data-id='3'>
  <div class='prototypeDiv' data-id='5'>123<div>
</div>
```